# *ngFor inside *ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

I have an array that holds a user's orders, and inside of it there is another array that holds his ordered items:
[image]

My question is: how do I loop through his orders[] -> orderItems[]

For now, I did it manually just to make sure it works

**HTML file:**

```js
 <tbody class="text-center">
                <tr *ngFor = "let order of myOrders;">
                    <td>{{order.orderItems[0].product_Name}}</td>
                    <td>{{order.orderItems[0].product_Price | currency: '$'}}</td>
                    <td>{{order.orderItems[0].product_Quantity}}</td>
                    <td colspan="6">{{order.orderItems[0].product_Price* order.orderItems[0].product_Quantity | currency: '$'}}</td>
                </tr>
                
            </tbody>
```

**TS file:**

```js
export class ProfileOrdersComponent implements OnInit {

  myOrders: OrderDetails[];
  constructor(private userService : UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getProfileOrders().subscribe((data:OrderDetails[]) =>{
      this.myOrders = data
      console.log("My Orders:", this.myOrders);
    })
  }

}
```

Appreciated!

Comment: use `*ngfor` again, whats the issue??

Comment: You can take a look at this sample for nested ```*ngFor``` in angular https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-ngfor-in-table-bn1psu

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to render html

```html
<tbody class="text-center">
  <tr *ngFor="let order of myOrders;">
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr *ngFor="let orderItem of order.orderItems">
          <td>{{orderItem.product_Name}}</td>
          <td>{{orderItem.product_Price | currency: '$'}}</td>
          <td>{{orderItem.product_Quantity}}</td>
          <td colspan="6">{{orderItem.product_Price* orderItem.product_Quantity | currency: '$'}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>

</tbody>
```